# How to put insert statement in SQL function?

Tags: sql-server

Here is my function which I am trying

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CreateNewRow] 
( @pFirstName VARCHAR(50), @pLastName VARCHAR(50) )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] ( [FirstName], [LastName] )
VALUES ( @pFirstName, @pLastName )

RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO
```

Please let me know alternative way if possible.

Comment: This behaviors is no supported. Check about stored procedures... `Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'INSERT' within a function.`

Comment: DML operations are not allowed in functions in SQL Server, you can use Stored Procedures. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/79be4014-3a05-4b48-a723-ac7888ff59df/why-dml-operations-are-not-allowed-in-functions-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert will not work in SQL function, Your function will give below error.

> Server: Msg 443, Level 16, State 2, Procedure CreateNewRow, Line 7
>   Invalid use of 'INSERT' within a function.

Alternative
use user-defined function that uses the INSERT command but the modified table is a table variable local to the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Ins_GetMaxValue]
( @pInt1 INT, @pInt2 INT, @pInt3 INT, @pInt4 INT )
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @IntTable TABLE ( [IntValue] INT )
DECLARE @MaxValue INT

INSERT INTO @IntTable ( [IntValue] ) VALUES ( @pInt1 )
INSERT INTO @IntTable ( [IntValue] ) VALUES ( @pInt2 )
INSERT INTO @IntTable ( [IntValue] ) VALUES ( @pInt3 )
INSERT INTO @IntTable ( [IntValue] ) VALUES ( @pInt4 )

SELECT @MaxValue = MAX( [IntValue] )
FROM @IntTable

RETURN @MaxValue
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using stored procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateNewRow] @pFirstName VARCHAR(50)
    ,@pLastName VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] (
        [FirstName]
        ,[LastName]
        )
    VALUES (
        @pFirstName
        ,@pLastName
        )

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
GO
```

To Call your Stored Procedure

```
EXEC CreateNewRow @pFirstName = 'Xxx'
    ,@pLastName = 'Yyy'
```